# My New Website Show me DNS Error Website Could Not Found

Tags: web

I have bought a new domain but it showing DNS error to me Check Please and Give Solution https://wisheshub.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine in my browser , probably you should have waited for the DNS server to update [image]